# Можно ли получить значение data атрибутов в переменную php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Есть календарь на `wordpress` который выводится на определенных страницах в виде месяца разбитого по дням в ячейках.

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при наведении мыши на каждый из дней вычислялось значение относительно заданного и числовой результат передавался на сервер, чтобы вытащить определенный контент из базы по этому параметру.

Первый этап с вычислением результата я сделал путем передачи `data` атрибута в `js`.

```
<div id="trekdays" data-date="<?php echo $days[0]->day; ?>"></div>

$(".Calendar days").mouseover(function() {
   var trekdays = $("#trekdays").data('date');
   var x = new Date(trekdays);
   var diff = Math.floor((y.getTime() - x.getTime()) / 86400000);
   $("#trek_excerpt").attr('data-excerpt', diff);
});
```

Проблема у меня возникает на обратном этапе передачи параметров из `js` в `php`

```
<p id="trek_excerpt" data-excerpt="">
<?php if( get_field('trek_excerpt_day_1') ): the_field('trek_excerpt_day_1'); endif; ?>
</p>
```

В атрибут `data-excerpt` результат записывается и обновляется - ок, но мне нужно, чтобы менялась переменная дней на `trek_excerpt_day_1`, `trek_excerpt_day_2` , `trek_excerpt_day_3` и т.д.

Можно ли записать значения `data` атрибутов в переменную `php`?

Пробовал передавать результат в `ajax`, но непонятно какой прописывать путь - шаблона страницы? И если таких страниц несколько

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "page-sample-page.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { val : diff }
});
```

А, если в `php` вот так записываю, то записываются только исходный `html` элемента

```
   $str = '<p id="trek_excerpt" data-excerpt="">Data</p>';
   echo $str;
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $d=$doc->loadHtml($str);
   $a = $doc->getElementById('trek_excerpt');
   var_dump($a->getAttribute('data-excerpt'));
```

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js "Как передать переменную из яваскрипта в PHP?
Точно так же, как и любые другие данные - послав запрос на сервер.
Но надо четко понимать, что во время выполнения php скрипта получить что-либо из яваскрипта, разумеется, невозможно. Передать можно будет только при следующем запросе. И обрабатывать его будет уже другой PHP скрипт. "

Comment: @Alexey Ten как эта информация решает мой вопрос? Не на словах, а в коде вы можете привести пример как предлагаете сделать?

Comment: можете зарегистрировать функцию-обработчик ajax-запросов так, как предписывает wp-кодекс и указывать admin-ajax.php в качестве пути. Если хотите обрабатывать данные в шаблоне страницы, то просто оставьте url (или action формы) пустыми, тогда ваш запрос будет стучаться по текущему адресу и его можно будет обрабатывать в соответствующем шаблоне страницы (только не забывайте про особенности работы с ajax-запросами в php)

Comment: @alenkins спасибо, а про особенности могли бы напомнить? вдруг упущу

Comment: Какой-то особой магии нет, но я, например, иногда забывала остановить выполнение остальных скриптов шаблона конструкцией `die()` или `exit`. И получалось, что постучался на страницу для того чтобы выполнить пару арифметических операций, а сервер пересобрал целый документ.